# OSX 10.8 Contacts can't access Active Directory 2003 via LDAP

Tags: macos, contacts, active-directory, ldap

I've recently upgraded to OSX 10.8 and have discovered that the Contacts Application can no longer access our Active Directory 2003 domain via LDAP. I have confirmed that the exact same settings work for OSX 10.7 and Mac OSX 10.6 which are [generalised to]:

```
Server: dc01.subdomain.domain.com.au  
Port: 389  
Searchbase: DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com,DC=au  
Scope: Subtree  
Authentication: Simple  
Username: domain\username  
Password: password
```

If I do a search on the LDAP with these setting I just get a spinning progress indicator. Console doesn't seem to display any errors with contacts.

Does anybody know if there are any workaround to getting 10.8 contacts to read AD 2003 LDAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the port from 389 (Apple's default) to 3268.  I had the exact same problem until I switched the port number.

Credit the [OS X Hints folks](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070323044211139) for solving this one.